# SOM for clustering words

Tags: python, data-science, cluster-analysis, som

I have a question... I am trying to implement clustering of words in the text using COM. But the examples I found do not allow processing a large amount of data. Could you please share links to projects that have implemented this task.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: what do you consider "large"?